# How do I build and run coroutine basics examples?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm just trying to follow the instructions on [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html), which state to run the following code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch { // launch new coroutine in background and continue
        delay(1000L) // non-blocking delay for 1 second (default time unit is ms)
        println("World!") // print after delay
    }
    println("Hello,") // main thread continues while coroutine is delayed
    Thread.sleep(2000L) // block main thread for 2 seconds to keep JVM alive
}
```

I have this code in a file at my-kotlin-library/src/main/kotlin/coroutines.kt. This is my build.gradle, located in the root my-kotlin-library directory:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.21"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
}
```

I can build with `gradle build`, which produces the following artifacts (only showing relevant):

```
build
├── classes
│   └── kotlin
│       └── main
│           ├── CoroutinesKt$main$1.class
│           ├── CoroutinesKt.class
│           └── META-INF
│               └── my-kotlin-library.kotlin_module
└── libs
    └── my-kotlin-library.jar
```

There are no build errors, yet when I try to run it I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
$ kotlin -cp build/libs/my-kotlin-library.jar CoroutinesKt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/GlobalScope
    at CoroutinesKt.main(coroutines.kt:4)
    at CoroutinesKt.main(coroutines.kt)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.AbstractRunner.run(runners.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.run(Main.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.main(Main.kt:119)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 9 more
```

I found the coroutines jar file and tried including it in the classpath also:

```
$ kotlin -cp ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.1.1/3d2b7321cdef9ebf9cb7729ea4f75a6f6457df86/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:build/libs/my-kotlin-library.jar CoroutinesKt
```

Unfortunately this produced the same error. I must have something configured incorrectly, but I can't find a good example of building and running using coroutines outside of Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution, but I'll leave the question open for a little while in case someone else know a better way. I just needed to replace the tilde with `$HOME`:

```
$ kotlin -cp $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.1.1/3d2b7321cdef9ebf9cb7729ea4f75a6f6457df86/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:build/libs/my-kotlin-library.jar CoroutinesKt
```

After adding the application plugin and specifying a main class name in my build script, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55412882/1015595), I was able to run with `gradle run`. However, I wasn't really able to observe the messages being printed to the console with the delays as intended. I was able to see how Gradle was running my class with `gradle run -i`, which produced a command similar to the one above, except it called `java -jar` and had all the following paths in the classpath:

```
/Users/dave.kennedy/Code/kotlin/my-kotlin-library/build/classes/java/main
/Users/dave.kennedy/Code/kotlin/my-kotlin-library/build/classes/kotlin/main
/Users/dave.kennedy/Code/kotlin/my-kotlin-library/build/resources/main
/Users/dave.kennedy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.1.1/3d2b7321cdef9ebf9cb7729ea4f75a6f6457df86/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar
/Users/dave.kennedy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.21/4bcc2012b84840e19e1e28074284cac908be0295/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.21.jar
/Users/dave.kennedy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-common/1.1.1/7ed04382bdf0c89c5d87ac462aa4935ae8e85243/kotlinx-coroutines-core-common-1.1.1.jar
/Users/dave.kennedy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.21/f30e4a9897913e53d778f564110bafa1fef46643/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.21.jar
/Users/dave.kennedy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar
```

When running with the `kotlin` command, the stdlib is automatically added to the classpath along with some additional jars.

Answer (score 1):

You should either configure your gradle build to create an uber-jar that contains all your dependencies and has a declared main class that you can run simply with `java -jar <jarname>`, or you should let gradle build and run your program.

To make the latter work, add this to `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'CoroutinesKt`
```

and then write

```
$ gradle run
```

at the command line.

Comment: While this works, it creates some odd timing issues. I was able to see the actual command being run by Gradle with `gradle run -i`, which is really similar to the answer I posted below. I'll share more details there.